# Track on screen rendering

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I m trying to track after the **screen rendering** in `Android` for move a simple Object on screen but with no luck.

For Example: The background and the bars in flappy bird game, How does they "move" and the bird is flying like?!

I m trying to avoid from using `OpenGL`.

Any tutorial? Any Tip/Trick?

In iOS it's super simple, In android is it the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build a game (especialy if you build it for android and IOS) and need to use some tweening go and use platform such as

Corona:
http://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/

Unity:
http://unity3d.com/

you could use openGL but this is a lot of power for some little app...

if you just want animations you could try to use the android animations:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

also a nice tutorial for animations and tweening:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-simple-tween-animation--mobile-14898

or extend the view class and override onDraw, this way you could draw stuff on a canvas and even create your own animations by calling invalidate() again.

all depend on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! @adi and @Queen_Gili! In iOS I can track after the screen rendering (60 frame per second or less). In Android I want the same. Please notice it's not an animation (View Animation or Animation Property), I want to make Object to move when the screen refresh. For example, how's the flappy bird game works?!